# Android - How to use a search query result to populate a listview in a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, search, android-intent, action

I am trying to start a project but the first part requires me to figure out how to populate a listview using the results of a search query.  I was looking at the SearchManager in Android to create an intent to submit a search, but I could not find an example that showed how the results get returned and how to then do the other thing I need to do, to use the say first 10 results to populate a listview.  I know how to do the rest of what I want to do, but this first part has me stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#example

It uses a Loader when the text in the Search input changes. When the text changes, the loader is restarted with `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);` , and when the loader finishes searching, it updates the Adapter :

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
```

Before that, we already set the adapter for the class, which is a `ListFragment`, so that the list in the screen is linked to the adapter and its content :

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null,
            new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```